# How to avoid that glassfish deploys all the previous project?

Tags: deployment, glassfish, config

When I start the glassfish server I have noted that it loads all the previous projects that i have developed and previously deployed.
I think that somewhere there is a config file that tells the server to reload the projects, but if i would like to work just on one of them what i have to do?
i suppose that i have to change or delete some entry in a glassfish configuration file, but i don't know where it is and how to do that.

thanks
Massimo

Comment: That's really not clear. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

You have different options.

You can go to the Glassfish admin GUI via `http://localhost:4848` and look under "Applications". You can undeploy properly deployed applications there.

If this is not working you can manually delete the applications from the glassfish folder: Look at

> /[glassfish_installation_path]/glassfish/domains/[your_domain]/applications

or

> /[glassfish_installation_path]/glassfish/domains/[your_domain]/autodeploy

Glassfish is running applications in these folders at startup time.

The undeployment depends somehow on the method you used to deploy the applications...if you used NetBeans to deploy you can probably even select the application in NetBeans and click "Clean and build" do undeploy it.

Comment: Don't try to delete the applications directly from the folder. There are references to these apps in the domain.xml file, so it will break your domain. One other possibility is to use the asadmin command line utility.